# How to make whole row in table act like hyperlink (open in new tab etc) in ngtable (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using AngularJS with ngtable.

Every time when I'm creating a table I put `ui-sref` on `<tr>` element like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="element in $data" ui-sref="app.some.details.info({id: element.id})">
  <td>{{element.name}}</td>
  <td>{{element.info}}</td>
</tr>
```

However, this doesn't allow the user to open entry in a new tab, right-click on it to open in a new window, etc (it doesn't act like `<a>` )

Is there any way that I could make the whole row clickable with the option to open in new tab/window (like in the  case)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a function, `$state.href` and `window.open`.

Also use a variable to control whether new tab or not:

```
// <tr ng-repeat="element in $data" ng-click="navigateTo(element.id, false)"> -- Same Tab
<tr ng-repeat="element in $data" ng-click="navigateTo(element.id, true)">
  <td>{{element.name}}</td>
  <td>{{element.info}}</td>
</tr>

...

//In the controller
$scope.navigateTo = function(id, inNewTab){
  if(inNewTab){ // New tab
     var url = $state.href('app.some.details.info', {id: id});
     window.open(url , "_blank")
  } else { // Same tab
     $state.go('app.some.details.info', {id: id});
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case it will always open in a new tab right? Like I have stated I would like to have an option to open in new tab, not always open in new tab

Comment: @lukaszrys You can add a variable for the same. Check edit

Comment: thanks for the reply. While that's true I'd like for it to be controllable by the user not by the developer. I guess your solution could be adapted to open in a new tab if someone holds CTRL button but it still doesn't cover the `<a>` behaviour

Comment: @lukaszrys Have you tried to wrap the row inside an `<a>` tag and set `ui-sref` to that?

Comment: Do you mean putting `<td>` elements in `<a>`? Yeah, I did but it's getting ignored. I will accept it once it will meet my questions/concern.

Comment: @lukaszrys As such getting the exact functionality like an anchor tag would not be possible because things like right-click > open in new tab is native only to those. For full functionality you might need to use div tags with appropriate styling and wrap anchor tags around them. It can't be achieved with the table, tr, td tags. My answer is as far as you can go with those tags

Answer (score 1):

Yo ! If you want your row content acting like an `<a />` element, maybe you can wrap your `<td>` content with an anchor. Something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="element in $data" ui-sref="app.some.details.info({id: element.id})">
  <td>
    <a href="#" title="...">{{element.name}}</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" title="...">{{element.info}}</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

You can also create some custom javascript that will recreate `<a />` behaviour. Create click listener for each table row and use `window.location.href = ...`.

Comment: yeah thats one way to workaround it but still it's not super elegant way to make it